# keep MacBook Pro from powering on unexpectedly

Tags: power, startup

Powered off 2016 15" MacBook Pro running Big Sur unexpectedly powers on. Happens whether lid is open or closed. Seems only to happen when plugged in.

"Wake for network access" is disabled in System settings.

Computer gets hotter waiting on the login screen than it ever has.

Answer (score 1):

SMC reset right after shutdown keeps the machine off until I start it again. Will edit as I know more.

Comment: Excellent. The edit function here lets you keep the answer updated as you learn more.